# Convert a string with /n into comma separated string in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a string in groovy where every item is a new line

```
change_list = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'cd $WORKSPACE/p4c && git diff ${cid} origin/${CHANGE_TARGET} --name-only'

print change_list

print change_list.getClass()
```

Below is the output

```
Jenkinsfile

extensions/idpf/BaseCtrlTables.cpp

extensions/idpf/CollectProgramData.cpp

extensions/idpf/CollectProgramData.h

extensions/idpf/FormApplyTree.cpp
```

I want to convert it into a string with the newline changed as comma separated, or a new list with each element as 1 item

Answer (score 2):

```
List list = change_list.readLines()
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#readLines()

Or

```
String[] array = change_list.split(/\n/)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: `def commaString = change_list.readLines().findAll().join(',')`

Comment: `findAll()` not required in this line - right?

Comment: Depends if there's blank lines like in the Q